# Having trouble to have clickhouse consume Azure Event Hub Message

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to use clickhouse kafka engine to consume messages from Azure Eventhub (which supports same kafka protocol 1.0 or later). But it didn't work.

Here is what I have done,

1.Config kafka settings in clickhouse config.xml

```xml
`<kafka>
    <security_protocol>sasl_plaintext</security_protocol>
    <sasl_mechanism>PLAIN</sasl_mechanism>
    <sasl_username>$ConnectionString</sasl_username>
    <sasl_password>{Token}</sasl_password>
    <debug>all</debug>
    <auto_offset_reset>latest</auto_offset_reset>
</kafka>`
```

2.Setup kafka engine table to consume Azure Event Hub namespace

```sql
  CREATE TABLE queue (
    timestamp UInt64,
    level String,
    message String
  ) ENGINE = Kafka('{NameSpace}.servicebus.windows.net:9093', '{TopicName}', '$Default', 'CSV');
```

3.Send messages to Event hub.

4. Query kafka engine table, but got 0 rows returned.

```sql
SELECT * FROM queue
/* Ok.
0 rows in set. Elapsed: 15.014 sec. */
```

Here is the clickhouse server log.

```sh
2020.07.20 22:32:23.721576 [ 98101 ] {c3486e06-083b-4387-a563-4ff7d488ac39} <Trace> StorageKafka (queue): Can't get assignment

2020.07.20 22:32:23.721916 [ 98101 ] {c3486e06-083b-4387-a563-4ff7d488ac39} <Trace> StorageKafka (queue): Nothing to commit.

2020.07.20 22:32:23.722445 [ 98110 ] {c3486e06-083b-4387-a563-4ff7d488ac39} <Debug> MemoryTracker: Peak memory usage (for query): 0.00 B.
```

The log says can't get assignment. Has anyone tried Event Hub and what is the possible missing step?

Comment: could you check that events from Azure EventHub came to related Kafka-topic?

Comment: Yes, I've verified from EventHub side, the message is in the kafka topic.

Comment: try to check the *error* log - */var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log* not only *clickhouse-server.log*

Comment: I produced new messages today, and I've checked the error log, there is no error for today.

Comment: look at this one [ClickHouse Kafka Engine FAQ](https://www.altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-kafka-engine-faq)